# Can't execute sdkmanager from terminal

Tags: java, android-studio, appium, apple-m1, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install Appium on my M1 Mac and have issue with running sdkmanager from terminal.

I've installed OpenJDK8, i've installed latest Android Studio and cmdline-tools for it. Also i set paths for .zshrc

If i try to execute `sdkmanager` in terminal i've got this. I can't figure out what i did wrong

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:670)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:652)
```

I've tried to completely remove Java from mac, and reinstalled Android Studio after installing OpenJDK8. That doesn't help

Comment: Did you reset your JAVA_HOME environment variable as well?

Comment: `class version 55.0` is Java 11. That's why it's not working with OpenJDK8

Comment: Version 55 needs Java 11 or higher https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history